# Add wildcard for String check

Tags: java

I use this code to check incoming IP in list of IPs.

```
String[] list = merchant.getAllowed_ip_address()

if (!Arrays.stream(list.split(","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .noneMatch(request.getRemoteAddr()::equals)) {
    // Not in array
}
```

I would like to configure `*` as list content and allow all incoming IPs.

Can you advice how this can be implemented?

Comment: I think you meant to define ```list``` as a ```String```, not a ```String[]``` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do that. For example:

```
String[] list = merchant.getAllowed_ip_address()

if (Arrays.asList(list).contains("*")) {
    return true;
}

if (!Arrays.stream(list.split(","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .noneMatch(request.getRemoteAddr()::equals)) {
    // Not in array
}
```

Or you can define some boolean field if you do not want to check for specific IP.

```
String[] list = merchant.getAllowed_ip_address()
boolean anyIPAllowed;

if (anyIPAllowed) return true;
```